# Which ups vendors/models are supported by vmware esxi, if any?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've googled and searched the vmware site but have been unable to find an hcl for ups vendors or models.  I'm assuming esxi has power mgt that will shutdown guest following a certain time period without power.

Comment: Our current solution is a linux machine running apcupsd, which then uses SSH keys to do a `poweroff`, so I'm also interested in this.

Comment: Still confused as to why power management is not built into vmware's product.  In my opinion, this should be an integral part of any base layer, hypervisor or os.  After much research, it looks like the best supported option is through apc using a smartups, network management card, and powerchute network shutdown for vmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think ESXi has this on its own, this is the type of capability that you need either full ESX and the Service Console or ESXi managed by Virtual Center so that you have access to the VI API's. If you are using ESXi in a VI environment you can take a look at [GhettoShutdown on the VIOPS site](http://viops.vmware.com/home/docs/DOC-1341).